# Creating objects in an array for a menu

Tags: java, arrays, swing, object, jbutton

I'm trying to create a registration menu but I'm having trouble creating the objects in an accessible array.
Super class constructor:

```
Login(String fn, String ln, String acc, String by, String pw){
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    account = acc;
    birthYear = by;
    password = pw;
}
```

In the super class I created an array of type `Login`. In the child class `Register`, I'm trying to create objects in the array. My registration menu has several fields to be filled in. I want an error message to pop up when the fields are empty and when the password fields do not match.

```
JButton btnRegister = new JButton("Register");
btnRegister.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        boolean match = false;
        while (match == false){
        if (textField_4.getText().equals(textField_5.getText())){
        try{
            for (int i = count; i<= list.length;i++){
            list[i] = new Login(textField.getText(),textField_1.getText(),textField_2.getText(),textField_3.getText(),textField_4.getText());
            count++;
            match = true;
            }}
            catch (Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fields are empty", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                System.out.println(e);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            match = false;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password fields do not match!", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

I have gotten the password mismatch feature to work but I currently get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` thrown when I try to enter all of the fields and create an object. How do I resolve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the exception. how we know that at which line you are getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Please provide some testable and complete code.

Comment: @Braj It doesn't tell me a line. It just prints "java.lang.NullPointerException" in the terminal.

Comment: last three line are not enclosed in else part using brackets. what do you think?

Comment: You're missing a '}' after the `else` statement.

Comment: Don't use `System.out.println(e);`, use `e.printStackTrace()` instead, then it will tell you where the error is, my guess it's `list[i] = ..` which is probably not initialised...

Comment: @MadProgrammer I learn this last time from you.

Comment: @MadProgrammer That's a good tip. Here are the results:

    java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Register$1.actionPerformed(Register.java:78)

Which indicates that it is the for loop

Comment: list[i] is not initialized. Do I have to do that?

Comment: @JoshUrbanDavis Yess. Uninitialized fields are a common cause of NPE

Comment: Alright. I've initialized the array and now I'm getting a different error:
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at Register$1.actionPerformed(Register.java:83) On the same line.

Comment: Step back an consider your logic for a minute. For every press of the button, you are trying to fill the entire array with the same `Login`. Maybe a better solution would be to use a `ArrayList<Login>` and when the button is pressed, just a `logins.add(new Login(....))`. Give that a shot and see what happens.

Comment: It's likely that list is null (list.length)

Comment: Arrays in Java are 0 indexed, so "for (int i = count; i<= list.length;i++){" will cause an index out of bounds because of the "<= list.length", because you only access elements from 0 to list.length - 1

Comment: Don't use `getText()` for password field. Its deprecated as per [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText%28%29) for some security reason. Instead use [getPassword()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getPassword%28%29) that returns `char[]` and use it to match password.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the tips and help. I really appreciate it. The trick was to use an arraylist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit is most likely these two lines

```
    for (int i = count; i<= list.length;i++){
    list[i] = ...
```

Trying to access "*list[list.length]*" will give you an *ArrayIndexOutOfBounds*, since indeces start at 0, so *list*'s last index is *list.length-1*;

Change from "*i<= list.length*" to "*i < list.length*".